# Merge columns with column name as a separator

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have a data frame and would like to merge the values of several columns, as selected using a vector of column names, with each value interspersed with a comma and the column name. I'm struggling to work out how! Here's a simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
  Age = c(25, 30, 27),
  Country = c("USA", "Canada", "UK"),
  Occupation = c("Engineer", "Doctor", "Teacher")
)

selected_cols <- c("Age", "Country")

df <- df %>%
mutate(merged = ...)
```

Expected output is a new column with these values:

```
Age:25, Country:USA
Age:30, Country:Canada
Age:27, Country:UK
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Is your expected output a frame, a CSV, a vector of strings, or something else?

Comment: A new column please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(newcol = do.call(paste, c(Map(paste0, selected_cols, ":", pick(all_of(selected_cols))), list(sep = ", "))))
#      Name Age Country Occupation                 newcol
# 1   Alice  25     USA   Engineer    Age:25, Country:USA
# 2     Bob  30  Canada     Doctor Age:30, Country:Canada
# 3 Charlie  27      UK    Teacher     Age:27, Country:UK
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"), Age = c(25, 30, 27), Country = c("USA", "Canada", "UK"), Occupation = c("Engineer", "Doctor", "Teacher")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! In the real example, the columns are large numbers. Is there a way to format them so they're in scientific notation with `formatC(value, format = "e", digits = 1)`? I seem to be able to do it with `round(value, 1)`, but not with `formatC`.

Comment: before `paste`ing them, you can `sprintf("%0.0f", .)` the numeric columns to get _exactly_ the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(newcol = paste(
    map_vec(selected_cols, ~ paste0(.x, ":", as.character(get(.x)))),
    collapse = ", "
  ))
```

```
 Name      Age Country Occupation newcol                
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>                 
1 Alice      25 USA     Engineer   Age:25, Country:USA   
2 Bob        30 Canada  Doctor     Age:30, Country:Canada
3 Charlie    27 UK      Teacher    Age:27, Country:UK
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `tidy::unite` with an intermediate `mutate` step to add the column names as prefixes:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(
    all_of(selected_cols),
    ~ paste(cur_column(), .x, sep = ":"),
    .names = "{.col}1"
  )) |>
  tidyr::unite("new_col", all_of(paste0(selected_cols, 1)), sep = ", ")
#>      Name Age Country Occupation                new_col
#> 1   Alice  25     USA   Engineer    Age:25, Country:USA
#> 2     Bob  30  Canada     Doctor Age:30, Country:Canada
#> 3 Charlie  27      UK    Teacher     Age:27, Country:UK
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively please try the below code with `cur_column`, `syms`

```r
df %>% mutate(across(selected_cols, ~ paste0(cur_column(), ':', .x), .names = '{col}_new'),
              newcol=paste(!!! syms(paste0(selected_cols,'_new')),sep = ',')
              ) %>% select(-ends_with('_new'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
     Name Age Country Occupation                newcol
1   Alice  25     USA   Engineer    Age:25,Country:USA
2     Bob  30  Canada     Doctor Age:30,Country:Canada
3 Charlie  27      UK    Teacher     Age:27,Country:UK
```